# How to build TCP connection between two different computers in local network in C#?

Tags: c#, tcp

I am trying to use C# to develop a client running on a computer and a server running on another computer in local network. I want to let the client connect to the server using TCP socket. When I run client and server on one computer they can be connected but the connection cannot be built when client and server on different server. I guess the problem is the IP address. When I run them on one computer I use localhost as the IP address of both of them. So how can I deal with this problem when they are running on different computers in local network?

Comment: Have you allowed that port of yours in firewalls of those computers?

Comment: add some code to show how you do it

Comment: When you create a Client object, you should specify an IP address of server to connect to, not "localhost". To know your server IP you can use `ipconfig` command from server command line.